# set orientation not locking to portrait

Tags: cordova, appframework

I am building a mobile application using Cordova and Intel app framework. I try to set the orientation to portrait mode

```
var onDeviceReady = function () {        
    intel.xdk.device.setRotateOrientation('portrait');
    intel.xdk.device.setAutoRotate(false);
    intel.xdk.device.hideSplashScreen();

};
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready", onDeviceReady, false);`
```

But when I check the build by installing the APK in Android 4.4, it doesnt work. It always rotate in both modes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using Cordova/PhoneGap you need to change the Orientation to "portrait" (normally it is "default") in the config.xml file in the app folder or www folder. `<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />`

The PhoneGap developer app does not reflect this change so you can test by building the app and running it.

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your config.xml:

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

this works for all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I asked almost the same question and tried everything I could find, even the answers from this question but it didn't work for me, I found a way though :

I ended up using [this](https://github.com/yoik/cordova-yoik-screenorientation) (GitHub link) plugin.

### The plugin is called **cordova-yoik-screenorientation** and all you need to do is:

Download the GitHub archive.

Copy the **plugin.xml** and **src** folder to your root file.

Copy **screenorientation.android.js**, **screenorientation.bb10.js**, **screenorientation.ios.js** and **screenorientation.js** to your **www** folder.

Add the following into your **index.html head**:

```
<script>
   screen.lockOrientation('landscape');
</script>
```

...you can change *landscape* to *portrait* if you want.

Comment: Awesome! The plugin works in iOS 8.1 and 8.3 :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this style works!

```
    <style>
        /* Landscape layout (with min-width) */
        @media screen and (min-aspect-ratio: 1/1) and (min-width:400px) {
            .app {
                background-position:left center;
                padding:75px 0px 75px 170px;  /* padding-top + padding-bottom + text area = image height */
                margin:-90px 0px 0px -198px;  /* offset vertical: half of image height */
                                              /* offset horizontal: half of image width and text area width */
            }
        }
    </style>
```